# Spring Security Configuration is not applied

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I have the below configuration where i need to configure `HTTPBasic` authentication for `/api/v1/**` endpoints and i want to configure `form` authentication for `/users/` url pattern. When i run with the below configuration, the configuration for web requests is working correctly but the configuration for API is not working. No security is being applied. Where am I going wrong?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Order(1)
    @Configuration
    public static class MVCSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean
        public BCryptPasswordEncoder getBCryptPasswordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.
                    antMatcher("/users/**")
                    .csrf()
                        .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/resources/**", "/users/register", "/users/signup", "/users/confirm", "/users/user-action", "/users/reset-password", "/confirm", "/webjars/**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/users/**")
                    .hasRole("USER")
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password");

            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/v1/users/**")
                    .hasRole("USER")
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have put your code to work with this configuration bellow:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

public class ApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/api/v1/users/**")
           .authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
           .hasRole("USER").and().httpBasic();
    }

}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class MVCSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/users/register", "/users/signup", "/users/confirm",
                        "/users/user-action", "/users/reset-password", "/confirm", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/users/**").hasRole("USER")
        .and()
        .formLogin().usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password");
    }
}

}
```

View docs for [Spring Security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Security-2.0#restoring-separation-of-basic-auth-for-actuator-endpoints-but-something-else-for-user-defined-endpoints) and sample code [here](https://github.com/mageddo/java-examples/tree/6a7dd2b426f17a1c5ebab1552f25e8c62d2d9aee/spring-security/basic-and-form-auth-together).